# Facebook App Requests - Object not owned by the app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am trying to implement Facebook App Requests in my android game using Unity3d.

Unity 5.6.2f1

Facebook SDK v7.10.1

I am doing following steps :

1. Created Facebook App and selected Category as Game and sub category strategy.
2. Make it live and public can be seen in screenshot
   [Screenshot of app status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LWyy.jpg)
3. Created an object in [Object Browser](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser) can be seen in screenshot
   [object Screenshot in Object Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f7MJ.png)
4. Integrated in unity using following function

```
 public static void AppRequest(
        string message, 
        OGActionType actionType,
        string objectId, // the id got from object browser
        IEnumerable to,
        string data = "",
        string title = "",    
        FacebookDelegate callback = null)
```

when i call this function on button click it shoes me following error

> Object Type 'Game' with for ID 'XXXXXXXXXX' is not owned by this App.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em3xy.jpg)

What i am doing wrong ? or missing something ?

P.S: i am trying to make a system in which user can share his game resources with his friends. Like Bullets, Power Ups etc. Kindly let me know what is best way to achieve this functionality ?

Thanks